# Should I implement both client and server-side validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have thought all along that I should validate form data on JavaScript when I click the submit button and after that moreover I should validate data submitted on server side C#.
But now I'm thinking that probably I don't need to validate form data on JavaScript? Because the page doesn't be reloaded anyway thanks to Ajax which means there is no difference for users between error message from JavaScript and error message from C#.

Strange thinking??

Comment: Something that none of the answer touched on is that ASP validators are rather nice if your validation requirements are sufficiently simple.  They will always do server side validation (unless explicitly disabled or ignored) and by default also perform client side validation.  When it's an option, I tend to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Always** implement validation on the server side. Then make sure that this validation works before even thinking about client side validation. The reason for this is that I have seen many people implement client side validation first and then forget about the server side validation thinking that they are validating something. Client side validation should not really be seen as validation. It should be seen as something that allows to improve the user experience (the user gets immediate feedback without the need to submit the entire form) and preserve bandwidth. So if you want this extra then go ahead and implement client side validation.

Answer (score 7):

You should **always** validate server side.

Validating client side is optional to increase usability.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is a good practice implement the validation on both server and client side(even if only the server side validation is mandatory).

The reasons why is because someone could by pass your client side validation breaking your domain integrity.

The client side validation is useful anyway to prevent round-trip to the server even when the validation fails on the client side

Answer (score 1):

If you had to do only 1, server side is certainly the way to go.

Although Ajax gives the user the "illusion" that the page is not posting, you are still generating HTTP traffic to your site so depending on what your hosting situation is, that may add unnecessary costs and load on your web server.

My .02 cents? With all the nice JS libraries out there today, there is no good reason to NOT implement client-side validation.

Comment: Well, one reason not to that comes to mind is that it's not always possible.  Say, for example, someone is entering a new username on registration.  You can only do server side validation to check if the username is already used.  Anything along those lines (you need a DB query to validate the data) can't be done on the client side.

Comment: That is 100% correct. I should have said to implement client-side validation whenever possible.

Comment: It bothers me to implement all the same validation on client-side and server-side when the validation is complex and it dere me to connect DB.

Comment: @TaichiSato If you can't be bothered then don't implement Client side validation.  If you (or your clients) find the increased usability worth the extra time, then put in the other time.  I imagine in the end it won't be up to you, it'll be up to your clients; do they want to pay for your time to implement client side validation.

Comment: I don't think they want to pay for that. Thanks.